# IntelliSense tooltip always shows the same three top hits (even w/o relation)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, intellicode

I am using *VS Code* for Python development. But with any Python file I edit, I always experience the same issue: the IntelliSense tooltip **always** shows the same 2-3 suggestions on top, regardless of what I am writing. Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am using the Microsoft Python language server and IntelliCode, but I experienced the same issue also before enabling IntelliCode. Do you have any ideas what might cause this behaviour?

Comment: This was duplicated as an [filed bug](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/2011) and received an answer.

Comment: @BrettCannon Exactly. I will post an answer here for the records and close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the records:

As it turned out and [discussed in this GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/2011) the problem comes from the "Python Extended" extension for VS Code. Uninstalling it solved the issue for me.